# Unable to show chatter messages in SF communities

Tags: community, customer-community

I don't know how to enable chatter settings for Community. This is my Chatter Settings:
[image]

Also I could see the Messages page on community.
[image]

But this page says there is a permission issue. Please tell me what am I supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because the administrator has restricted chatter permission on the profile level, If you are an administrator you should enable them from the Adminster- > Manage Users -> Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

One setting that might be causing this can be found under community administration preferences. In Salesforce, go to Setup -> Feature Settings -> Communities -> All Communities. Click on "Workspaces" for your community. Then click Administration. Finally, go to preferences, and check the box that says "Enable direct messages" under the General heading.

[image: Preferences]